# How to detect child collision other colliders?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My collider object has two child objects, there are camera and collider(is Triggered = true). I need to detect collision child collider and recognize all touched object by this child collider.

- gameObject(CapsuleCollider(isTriggered = false), Rigidbody)

  - gameObject(Camera)
  - gameObject(CapsuleCollider(isTriggered = true))

I think this is wrong code, but maybe not, at least just for some imagination:

```
CapsuleCollider legsTrigger;  
void Update()
    {
        legsTrigger= GetComponentInChildren<CapsuleCollider>();

        if(legsTrigger.contact...){
          Debug.Log("This is : ");
          Debug.Log(legsTrigger.gameObject.tag);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a monobehaviour to your child. Otherwise you can't detect. If you want to check it from your parent gameobject, [on this link](https://answers.unity.com/questions/986235/is-it-possible-to-check-collision-from-another-obj.html) there is a really nice solution for it by [rsodre](https://answers.unity.com/users/29416/rsodre.html). I copied the codes from it and converted from 2D colliders to 3D.

Firstly, create a Bridge script between parent gameobject and childs

```
 public class ColliderBridge : MonoBehaviour
 {
     ColliderListener _listener;
     public void Initialize(ColliderListener l)
     {
         _listener l;
     }
     void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
     {
         _listener.OnCollisionEnter(collision);
     }
     void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
     {
         _listener.OnTriggerEnter(other);
     }
 }
```

Then, add this ColliderBridge script to all childs, and then listen collision events from parent like this(Add ColliderListener script to parent gameobject).

```
public class ColliderListener : MonoBehaviour
 {
     void Awake()
     {
         // Check if Colider is in another GameObject
         Collider collider = GetComponentInChildren<Collider>();
         if (collider.gameObject != gameObject)
         {
             ColliderBridge cb = collider.gameObject.AddComponent<ColliderBridge>();
             cb.Initialize(this);
         }
     }
     public void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
     {
         // Do your stuff here
     }
     public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
     {
         // Do your stuff here
     }
 }
```

Comment: I edited the answer. Now it works for all 3D colliders, not just for CapsuleCollider. If you want it to work only for capsule collider just replace the line "Collider collider = GetComponentInChildren<Collider>();" with "CapsuleCollider collider = GetComponentInChildren<CapsuleCollider>();"